# What if Tortoise SVN unified diff viewer fail to start?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Quite often when there are many other applications running, Tortoise SVN's unified diff viewer can fail to show up - **with a quick splash and then disappears immediately**. But after closed some other applications, this diff viewer **might** act normally again. I suspect this is related to the available GDI resources left in system, according to my observation, though in fact any other applications (even heavy resource consumers like MSWord/Excel...) can start without problem.

Has anyone got any idea of solving this?

OS: Windows XP SP3
TortoiseSVN 1.6.16

[image]

Comment: I still get this is 1.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried use TortoiseUDiff.exe from TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 and problem solved. Seems should be bug in 1.6.16.